# stockwell transform

Tags: matlab, s-transform

I have a Matlab implementation for s-transform in this site http://pastebin.com/ErN81TPQ which depends on [this paper](http://djj.ee.ntu.edu.tw/S_Transform.pdf) . My problem is, at line 260, the implementer adds strange line by taking negative values,the original algorithm at 2.14 say it only positive values,but why he did added the negative values of the Gaussian to that ,shortly look at line 260 in the code and equation 2.14. the positive values should be only taken into consideration not those negative values

Comment: I'd recommend asking Mr. Robert Glenn Stockwell himself, or to refer to his paper mentioned in the code, "Localization of the Complex Spectrum: The S Transform"

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't find his email. nor his profile. i would love if you help me finding his email

Comment: I think this is him: http://map.nasa.gov/abstracts/stockwell.html